# BASE_URL in codeigniter shows different URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have received website code from somebody else & it's giving a lot of errors in loading. Every CSS, image or anything is loaded by this code

`href="<?php echo asset_url();?>/css/...`

Now I checked, `asset_helper.php` & found out this

```
function asset_url(){
    return BASE_URL.'public'
}
```

In my `config.php`, line says `$config['base_url'] = '';`.

Finally when I tried to `echo asset_url();`, it gives me `https://somerandomwebsite.com/...`. I'm not sure from where this is coming from.

Sorry I'm new to CodeIgnitor & tried everything I could to find out but there was no luck. Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: check the `constants.php` int the config folder.

Comment: @SayantanDas That was the culprit, thanks buddy. It was coming from there.

Answer (score 4):

Your Helper function might be using constant function. Check your **constan.php** file.

```
define(BASE_URL, "http://test.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first: the manual!
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=base_url#base_url

ok so they made a new function just to deal with an extra subfolder name in stead of just doing base_url(). 'public' or base_url('public') and have defined a BASE_URL somewhere which is not part of the core of CI. Track that BASE_URL down and kill it if possible. You can and should use base_url().

I use this for base_url (avoids hardcoded url):

```
$protocol = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$config['base_url'] = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

I usually *autoload* the thing in config/autoload.php:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```